# ImageButton with external image?

Tags: android, user-interface, imagebutton

I'm searching a way to put my own image as an ImageButton. There is the src thing but it accepts only icons i thing. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty fundamental stuff which would be covered if you ran through tutorials.

There's more to it, but the general common procedure would be to include any images you want to use in your res/drawable folder for the project. Then, you'd usually reference the image in XML something like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/myimage" />
```

Comment: yes i found that, have to save the image in the phone? what i put at "myimage"??

Comment: You have to include the image within the project in res/drawable folder